# DateTimeOffset localTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;

Tags: c#

The above code returns the local time and offset data where the application runs. For the same point in time the result of the above code will be different depending upon from where the code is excuted.
Is it correct?

How does it gets the local time? It uses the system time or it uses the geo location of the server?
Smith

Comment: You might want to think about using DateTime.UTCNow instead.  That way, no matter where the computer is located, it will always be the same locale.  Just translate the data afterwards to localtime for the user to see

Answer (score 0):

It works from the time settings of the machine in it is running on. If you take your machine abroad and don't update the time (or have it set to be automatic), or simply have it wrong, then the results will be wrong.

It's probably just as well to be wrong, since you'll be comparably wrong as every other application on the machine. Which makes you right, in a very very localised context ;)